# How to get a Kony application's name at runtime

Tags: debugging, mobile, cross-platform, temenos-quantum

I'm writing a logger module for a Kony app to print out debugging statements. The Kony SDK already has a `kony.print` function but I'd like this logger to print out the application's name as a prefix to each statement, to get something like:

```bash
FooApp: x is 1
FooApp: a is ["hello", "world"]
```

The point here is to make it easier for me to filter/find my debug statements in the Xcode or Android Studio logs while debugging.

So I'm aiming to write something like:

```js
var Logger = (function(){

    var prefix = ""; //kony.getAppId()?

    return{
        print: function(message){
            kony.print(`${prefix}: ${message}`);
        }
    };
})();
```

So the question is whether there is anything like a `kony.getAppId()` function, a constant or equivalent I can query to get the appropriate value for `prefix` in order to make the module reusable, rather than hard-code it for every project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that there's an `appConfig` variable built into every Kony app that includes useful information about the application like its name and version. So now I can initialise the `prefix` variable in my module like this:

```js
var prefix = appConfig.appId || appConfig.appName;
```

I hope this is useful to others.

Comment: You can also add a logcat message filter by log tag 'StandardLib' to get only the Kony prints in DDMS. For iOS, you can search by using the bundle identifier as the Process tag.